# currency conversion using a data frame

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe of transactions in different currencies (let's say USD, EUR, and CAD) where each row is a transaction and the currency is specified by the currency column and the date-specific conversion rate from given currency to CAD is specified in the proceeding columns

```
d = {'Value': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
     'Currency': ['CAD', 'USD', 'EUR', 'USD'],
     'CAD': [1,1,1,1],
     'USD': [1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.1],
     'EUR': [1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to define a new column in df which shows the transaction value converted into CAD. How can I do this programmatically, without using a loop?

Comment: is this dataframe correct? how can one interpret row 2 for example? or simply what does each column represent?

Comment: I want to add a new column, ValueCAD, where the value is Value*rate, where rate is one of CAD, USD, or EUR, depending on the currency. So the output should be:
ValueCAD 
1
2.4
4.2
4.4

Comment: which rate are you talking about? for example, the whole column of CAD is 1. how is that a rate??

Comment: CAD, USD, and EUR

Comment: how do you get 1, 2.4, 4.2 and 4.4??? what numbers are you multiplying to get that?

Comment: CAD is 1 because the default is CAD, so any any Value that is in CAD is the same

Comment: So for first case, ValueCAD is 1

Comment: then where do the other values come from?

Comment: ValueCAD = Value*(CAD, USD, or EUR) depending on the what the currency is according to the currency column

Comment: You can ignore CAD column if you want, answer I am looking for is how to get ValueCAD

Comment: I see what you need..

Comment: why don't you want to use a forloop??

Comment: `df.assign(ValueCAD=df.values[tuple(df.Currency.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(df.columns,range(len(df.columns)))).get(x)).reset_index().values.T)].astype(float)*df.Value)`

Comment: Onyambu - thanks, this works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use [`df.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
df["Value_in_CAD"] = df.Value * df.lookup(df.index, df.Currency)
```

which gives me

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
   CAD Currency  EUR  USD  Value  Value_in_CAD
0    1      CAD  1.4  1.3      1           1.0
1    1      USD  1.5  1.2      2           2.4
2    1      EUR  1.4  1.4      3           4.2
3    1      USD  1.4  1.1      4           4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.assign(ValueCAD = df.values[tuple(df.Currency.transform(lambda x: dict(zip(df.columns, 
         range(len(df.columns)))).get(x)).reset_index().values.T)].astype(float) * df.Value)
Out[230]: 
   Value Currency  CAD  USD  EUR  ValueCAD
0      1      CAD    1  1.3  1.4       1.0
1      2      USD    1  1.2  1.5       2.4
2      3      EUR    1  1.4  1.4       4.2
3      4      USD    1  1.1  1.4       4.4
```

You can also do:

```
df.merge(df.melt(['Value','Currency']).pipe(lambda x: x[x.Currency==x.variable].
         drop('variable',1)).pipe(lambda x:x.assign(ValueCAD=x.Value*x.value)).
         drop('value',1))
Out[241]: 
   Value Currency  CAD  USD  EUR  ValueCAD
0      1      CAD    1  1.3  1.4       1.0
1      2      USD    1  1.2  1.5       2.4
2      3      EUR    1  1.4  1.4       4.2
3      4      USD    1  1.1  1.4       4.4
```